# What is the reason for the four-way fight scene on the train?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, hitman

In [Hitman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0465494/), after watching the four-way fight scene on the train, many questions came to mind:

1. What is the reason why the three agents came to kill agent 47?
2. Why did they point their guns at each other and then fight each other?
3. If they were hired to kill agent 47, why did they point their guns at each other rather than point all their guns towards agent 47?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The agency hired them to kill him.
2. Only one can collect the bounty?
3. see number 2

Comment: You may be right.But,agent 47 was one of the best agent in "The Oraganization".Why don't they think to kill agent 47 together and spilt up the bounty rather than trying to kill each other.

Comment: From what I recall, there was a bit of a stand-still on the train, with no one having the upper hand on anyone else.  They then decide to do the respectable thing and fight it out, hand to hand.  Also, it didn't seem like they were ever taught team cooperation, so that could be a major factor why they didn't cooperate instead of competing.

Comment: Okay, we stop pointing guns at each other and aim at 47 ... no, after you, I insist.

Comment: Because the directors had a cool idea where they'd do an action sequence that was a four-way fight, and only needed the flimsiest of pretexts to justify it. That's like the movie Crank, where the directors were first-time directors who were cinematographers, so basically they had a bunch of "cool" scenes they wanted to do, and didn't really care if the story line to string them together was even mildly plausible. Looking for logic and reason in empty-headed action films is kid of a futile endeavor.

Comment: Probably my comment should have been placed in the question, not in the answer.